# Git commands execute very slowly on cmd.exe or powershell.exe, How to fix it?

Tags: windows, git

**windows version**: 10

**git version**:  2.35.1.windows.2

When using git commands on cmd or powershell, git will be hang, but on git bash, every command is ok, how to fix it?

On powershell:

on powershell:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdv0c.png

On git bash:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2kqj.png

My Graphics drivers is NVDIA is not AMD

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1160349/git-is-extremely-slow-on-windows) will resolve your problem.

And images you attached are not visible. It would be helpful if they are visible so that we can get clear picture.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry, I can't post images, but I re-edit my quesion, now can visit images by link